# Problem about Global.asax problem after deploy to Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, c#-4.0, web-deployment, global-asax

I have realized that after I deploy my project to Azure. The connection string of global.asax is not function and cause that the page that I use sql command for feature purpose were gone and cannot function. How can I fix it? Can the experiencer give the solution how to fix this problem? Thank you very much.

```
    //connection String
    public const string CS = @"
    Data Source=(LocalDB)\mssqllocaldb;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MTCompanyDB.mdf
    ;Integrated Security=True";
```

Answer (score 1):

LocalDb doesn't exist for Azure. LocalDb is a feature of SQL Server Express, there is no equivalency of that on the service (machine) you are deploying your App Service website on.

You could set the connectionstring in `web.config` and when you deploy to azure `Create a SQL Database`.

[image]

After publish, click `Configure` to open the publish settings.
[image]

Click `Use this connection string at runtime(update destination web.config)` which will use the Azure sql connectionstring when your webapp deploy to azure.
[image]

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase).